# ._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT occurs on simple urlopen

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, error-handling, timeout

I've got a problem which is this:

```
Sorry
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "testconn.py", line 2, in <module>
import httplib
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 680, in <module>
class HTTPConnection:
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 692, in HTTPConnection
timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, source_address=None):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'
```

I seriously didn't have this issue like 3 days ago, everything was working fine and now this.
Here's my code: (To mention that I tried adding timeout, I tried following the strict syntax of urlopen (Adding timeout aswell). Nothing seemed to do it.)

```
import httplib
import urllib2

headers = {"pragma" : "no-cache"}
req = urllib2.Request("http://google.com/", headers = header)
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)

print response
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check if you have your own `socket.py` file. That shadows import of  standard library `socket` module.

Find it, rename(or remove) it. You should also rename(or remove) `socket.pyc`.

---

BTW, the following line has a typo ( header **s** )

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://google.com/", headers = header)
#                                                           ^
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. Tried deleting & repasting & everything. Still got it.

Comment: @DanielCrangu, What do you get if you run this? `python -c "import socket; print(socket.__file__)"`

Comment: @DanielCrangu, See [this screencast](http://asciinema.org/a/6740) I just recorded.

Comment: Hello, for python -c "import socket; print(socket.__file__)" in C:\Python27 I get: \lib\socket.py\ For another directory (Desktop\PythonStuff\) I get "Sorry \n\ socket.pyc". Thank you a lot for your video, I tried following your steps but I still get the same error.

Comment: @DanielCrangu, Delete `socket.py` and `socket.pyc`. And try `python -c "import socket; print(socket.__file__)"`; make sure it print path to standard library socket module path. If not, remove that, too.

Comment: Still nothing. If I remove it, it says there's no such module. I did everything you said. Twice. Even rebooted the PC. I really didn't have this problem 4 days ago when it was just working fine. Anyways, due to the fact that you were super helpful, I'll accept the answer and I'll keep googling around. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielCrangu, If you have another system (virtual machine), try install Python and copy the modules you are testing. And test there. If it works in the another system, it indicates that `socket.py`/`socket.pyc` is still there.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the reason I was getting TONS of ImportErrors.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you're importing `Flask` in `socket.py` file, you should change file name to something else.